# Include two conditions in an IF Statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to include to conditions in a jQuery if statement.

This is my current code with the bold being what I'm trying to make work.

```
// Add scrolling Nav Bar
$(document).ready(function() {
  var navpos = $('.nav-bar').offset();
  console.log(navpos.top);
    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {

      if ($(window).scrollTop() > navpos.top && $(window).width() < 960)) {

        $('.site-header .grid--full').hide(200);
        $('.nav-bar-scroll').show(200);
       }
       else {
         $('.site-header .grid--full').show(200);
         $('.nav-bar-scroll').hide(200);
       }
    });
});
```

**if ($(window).scrollTop() > navpos.top && $(window).width() < 960)) {**

My ultimate goal is to hide the original header and display a new one when scrolling down the page.

Thank you kindly in advance!

Comment: What's not working with your current code?

Comment: What jquery version you are using ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have one `)` too many.

`if ($(window).scrollTop() > navpos.top && $(window).width() < 960))`

Should be `if ($(window).scrollTop() > navpos.top && $(window).width() < 960)` to be syntactically correct.

Opening up your Javascript Console in any browser will alert you to this error, which in my version of Firefox, reads: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')'` - indicating you had an incorrect number of parentheses.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.